# MySQL: Need to Query for missing records from various start dates

Tags: mysql, date

I have two tables that are linked by an ID, and one table has a start date, and the child (linked) table has weekly entries of data.  I need to be able to query and determine the ID's, that are missing a week's data, without knowing the actual dates.

```
Table1
ID INT
START_DATE DATE

Table2
ID INT (foreign Key to Table 1)
TRAN_DATE DATE
VALUE INT
```

Each INT might have a different start date, and the values are saved weekly (every Monday, Tuesday, etc... based on Start Date)

Some IDs will have missed posting their value one week, and I need to look back historically for when a record is missing.

Assuming a Start_Date of Sept 9, 2013, the dates would be (9/9/2013. 9/16/2013, 9/23/2013,...)  I need to see if TRAN_DATE for ID 1 is 9/9/2013, then add 7 days (9/16/2013), and check for that record, then add 7 days (9/23/2013) and check for that record to exist.  Then repeat for the different IDs. This would end with the current date, or any date into the future (if this is easier).

I can do this with a program simply enough, but I need to do this at a customer site and I can not distribute code into the site, so I need to try to do it with a query).

Comment: I assume you mean it needs to repeat up until now?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Yes, keep going to the current date, by a factor of 7 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query returns any gaps in table2:

```
select distinct id
from table2 t2
where t2.tran_date < now() - interval 7 day and
      not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2a
                  where t2a.id = t2.id and
                        datediff(t2a.tran_date, t2.tran_date) = 7
                 );
```

This assumes that the first transaction is not missing.  Is that possible?

Comment: In my case the first date should not be missing as an initial record was created.